# How do I find the difference in name popularity from the result of a 2 table query?

Tags: sql, mysqli

Let's say I have 2 tables:

```
table1 and table2
```

Table1 has values:

```
id(key), last_name(char)
```

Table 2 has values:

```
id(key), year_born(char)
```

I can join these 2 tables with:

```
SELECT last_name, year_born
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

How do I find which names increased most in popularity between 2 years that are 10 years apart?  Assuming table1 and table2 have thousands of entries each.

I tried:

```
SELECT last_name, name_year, COUNT(last_name) AS num
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY last_name, name_year
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

For example I want to see the most popular name increase from 2000 to 2010. How do I create a query that will result in showing the increase in popularity of a name?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one sub-query that returns the result from year 2000, and another that returns results for year 2010. Afterwards just join the two sub-queries and compare the results

Example:

```
SELECT  y2010.last_name,
        COALESCE(y2000.cnt, 0)  y2000 ,
        COALESCE(y2010.cnt, 0)  y2010 ,
        COALESCE(y2010.cnt, 0) - COALESCE(y2000.cnt, 0) changes
FROM    ( SELECT    last_name ,
                    COUNT(*) cnt
          FROM      table1
                    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
          WHERE     year_born = 2000
          GROUP BY  last_name
        ) as y2000
RIGHT JOIN 
        ( SELECT  last_name ,
                COUNT(*)  cnt
        FROM    table1
                INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
        WHERE   year_born = 2010
        GROUP BY last_name
        ) as y2010 
ON y2000.last_name = y2010.last_name
```

[SQLFiddle demo:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3febc/10)